# BXslider popup window issue - height problems

Tags: javascript, popup, bxslider

I am using bxslider, using a responsive design, multiple sliders and a popup window. The problem. I have the multiple sliders working and rescaling with browser size. The problem is with the popup. The popup cuts off the images.

*Note: My javascript skills are very limited, so please explain as much as possible. Examples are always best for non-coders like me.*

This post: [Bxslider in a pop up div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28239290/bxslider-in-a-pop-up-div) ... makes reference to the bx-viewport having a height of 0px (due to the fact that the initial image was hidden). So, the javascript tries to get the initial image size, but fails because no image was shown (no image = no image height). Once the second image is shown (due to the bxslider autoplay), the problem fixes itself.

I tried to use the solution on [Bxslider in a pop up div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28239290/bxslider-in-a-pop-up-div) but it didn't work with my code (it makes reference to monbxslider.js, which I do not use).

So, I see what is causing the problem ... but have no idea how to fix it. I've tried playing with the styles, but that doesn't work. Fixed height doesn't work, because each slider is different, and may have a different image. Below are snippets of my code....

**Header Javascript** info...

```
<link href="/js/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>


<!-- Popup Toggle -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle_menu(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e.style.display == 'block') e.style.display = 'none';
    else e.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

**Styles for Popup**

```
    [id^="popup-"], div[id*=" popup-"] { 
      display:none;
    }

    .window {   
        display:block;
        background:white;
        position:fixed;
        top:0; left:0;
        margin:50px 5% 0 5%; 
        width:90%;
        z-index: 1001;
      } 

      .window .close {
      width: 22px; height: 22px; background: #000; border-radius: 50%; border: 3px solid #fff; display: block; text-align: center; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; position: absolute; top: -10px; right: -10px; z-index: 1002;}
      .window .bx-viewport { min-height:200px !important; }
      .window .bx-viewport ul li img { width:100% !important; padding:10px; }
      .window .bx-viewport ul li { width:100% !important; }
    .windowoverlay { 
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        opacity:0.8;
        filter:alpha(opacity=80);
        z-index: 1000;
       }
```

**BxSlider CSS**

```
/**
 * BxSlider v4.1.2 - Fully loaded, responsive content slider
 * http://bxslider.com
 *
 * Written by: Steven Wanderski, 2014
 * http://stevenwanderski.com
 * (while drinking Belgian ales and listening to jazz)
 *
 * CEO and founder of bxCreative, LTD
 * http://bxcreative.com
 */


/** RESET AND LAYOUT
===================================*/

.bx-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    /* *zoom: 1; */
}

.bx-wrapper img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

/** THEME
===================================*/

.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
    background: #fff;

    /*fix other elements on the page moving (on Chrome)*/
    -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
    -moz-transform: translatez(0);
        -ms-transform: translatez(0);
        -o-transform: translatez(0);
        transform: translatez(0);
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30px;
    width: 100%;
}

/* LOADER */

.bx-wrapper .bx-loading {
    min-height: 50px;
    background: url(../images/bx_loader.gif) center center no-repeat #fff;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2000;
}

/* PAGER */

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#999;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager .bx-pager-item,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-controls-auto-item {
    display: inline-block;
    *zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a {
    background: #999;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    outline: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.active {
    background: #FFF;
}

/* DIRECTION CONTROLS (NEXT / PREV) */

.bx-wrapper .bx-prev {
    left: 10px;
    background: url(../images/controls.png) no-repeat 0 -32px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-next {
    right: 20px;
    background: url(../images/controls.png) no-repeat -43px -32px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-prev:hover {
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-next:hover {
    background-position: -43px 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -16px;
    outline: 0;
    width: 33px;
    height: 31px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a.disabled {
    display: none;
}

/* AUTO CONTROLS (START / STOP) */

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
    text-align: center;
    display:none; /*Hide Stop Button*/ 
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 11px;
    outline: 0;
    background: url(../images/controls.png) -86px -11px no-repeat;
    margin: 0 3px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start.active {
    background-position: -86px 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop {
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 9px;
    height: 11px;
    outline: 0;
    background: url(../images/controls.png) -86px -44px no-repeat;
    margin: 0 3px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop.active {
    background-position: -86px -33px;
}

/* PAGER WITH AUTO-CONTROLS HYBRID LAYOUT */

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-pager {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-controls-auto {
    right: 0;
    width: 35px;
}

/* IMAGE CAPTIONS */

.bx-wrapper .bx-caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #666\9;
    background: rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.75);
    width: 100%;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-caption span {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
    display: block;
    font-size: .85em;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_menu('popup-1">
<img src="/images/Feature1_300x300.jpg" alt="" />
</a>

<!-- Popup -->          
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slider1').bxSlider({
      mode: 'fade',
      auto: true,
      autoControls: true,
      pause: 90000,
      adaptiveHeight: true
    });
});
</script>
<div class="popup" id="popup-1">

    <div class="window">        
        <a href="#" onclick="toggle_menu('popup-1');">
            <div class="close">X</div>
        </a>

        <!-- Slider -->
        <ul id="slider1">
          <li><img src="/images/Feature1.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img src="/images/Feature2.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img src="/images/Feature3.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="windowoverlay"></div>
</div>
<!-- Popup END -->
```

Here is the site. Scroll down and click the van image for the popup:
http://www.amazingdg.com/clients/testsite/

Right now the popup starts as display:none. I tried making the display visible, and positioned "off screen", and then "move" the popup onto the visible screen when it is clicked.  However, the height was still not recognized. Anyone out there with some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out...

When I call the popup, I activate the slider when the popup is displayed (changing display:none to display:block). I was doing it before the popup was called, and that was where the problem was. So the image "height" is activated when the popup is activated, and then the slider is run.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function popupwin(Id) {
        var winname = document.getElementById(Id);
        if (winname.style.display == 'block') {
            winname.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            winname.style.display = 'block';     
            $('#slider<?php echo $slidr; ?>').bxSlider({
              mode: 'fade',
              auto: true,
              autoControls: true,
              pause: 90000,
              adaptiveHeight: true
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```